# I filter for a slice of a dataframe, how can I now set of one of the column values?

Tags: python, pandas

When I execute the following:

```
market_info_df.loc[(market_info_df['issue_status'] == '10') & (market_info_df['market_phase'] == '0') & (market_info_df['trading_state'] == '  ')].iloc[0]
```

I get back a `slice` of a dataframe. Here is what the slice looks like:

```
activity                                          0
msg_original_type                                 0
sequence_no                                       0
system_event                                       
timestamp                2021-12-13 15:17:28.593198
trading_status                                    1
market_state                                   None
```

I simply want to set the `market_state` value of the dataframe  to `OPENING_AUCTION`.

I tried doing:

```
first_row = market_info_df.loc[(market_info_df['issue_status'] == '10') & (market_info_df['market_phase'] == '0') & (market_info_df['trading_state'] == '  ')].iloc[0]

first_row['market_state'] = 'OPENING_AUCTION'
```

But when I now `print(market_info_df)`, the `market_state` for the slice is not set! Basically my code is setting the value of `market_state` for `first_row` (i.e. the slice of the dataframe) but not the value of the dataframe itself.

How can I map it in `market_info_df` rather than in `first_row`?

Comment: Would `market_info_df.loc[(market_info_df['issue_status'] == '10') & (market_info_df['market_phase'] == '0') & (market_info_df['trading_state'] == '  ')]['market_state'] = 'OPENING_AUCTION'` work? Not 100% sure if this is what you're asking but this will set the df's market state to `'OPENING_AUCTION'` where the inner condition is met.

Comment: No it doesn't because I want the first instance where the conditions are met- in your code it doesn't do this. That's where the `iloc[0]` comes in

Comment: Okay, then I think the same thing but with an iloc[0] should work. ```market_info_df.loc[(market_info_df['issue_status'] == '10') & (market_info_df['market_phase'] == '0') & (market_info_df['trading_state'] == '  ')]['market_state'].iloc[0] = 'OPENING_AUCTION'```. You just need the filtered df query on the left because you are setting a value for the dataframe.